# Unable to buy Shrike

Tags: tribes-ascend

I today played several matches as a [Juggernaut](http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Juggernaut) and had over 15000 credits, but I still wasn't able to buy Shrike. According to Wiki, [it costs 4500 credits](http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Vehicles), so I had more than enough. It allowed me to buy Grav Cycle and Beowulf, but not Shrike. Other players on the same server were able to buy that vehicle, so it wasn't disabled by the server. Why couldn't I buy the Shrike? Is there a limit of number of Shrikes that can be in a game at the same time?

Comment: I believe that if someone else on the team's in the shrike you can't buy it until its destroyed

Comment: @yx.: I think I've played a game where our team had at least 2 shrikes

Comment: hmm.. don't know then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems heavy classes cannot buy Shrike. I switched my class to Soldier and went to inventory station, and then I was able to buy Shrike.

Comment: Heavy classes have never been able to purchase the shrike.

Comment: It took me quite some time to figure this out as well. The only time the game tells you that heavies cant fly shrikes is when you attempt to get in an empty shrike as a heavy.